# stop animation javaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-animations

I want to stop the car next to the traffic lights. For now I can only stop it when it's close to it, but if it's far, it just passes the red light. I guess there's an infinite loop but the while I've ends when the car is next to the traffic lights

`toFixed` is used to get left position in a percentage:

```js
document.getElementById('stopLight').onclick = illuminateRed;
document.getElementById('slowLight').onclick = illuminateYellow;
document.getElementById('goLight').onclick = illuminateGreen;




function illuminateGreen() {
    clearLights();
    document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "green";
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("car");
 var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
  }
}

function illuminateRed() {
  clearLights();
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "red";

  var i;
  var continueA = true;

  while (continueA) {


    var positionCar = $('#car1').position();
    var percentCarLeft = positionCar.left / $(window).width() * 100;
    var positionPan = $('#traffic-light').position();
    var percentPanLeft = (positionPan.left / $(window).width() * 100) - 10;


    if ((percentCarLeft.toFixed(0) >= percentPanLeft.toFixed(0) - 10) && (percentCarLeft.toFixed(0) <= percentPanLeft.toFixed(0) + 5)) {

      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("car");
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

        x[i].style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "paused";

      }

      continueA = false;
    }

  }

}

function illuminateYellow() {
    clearLights();
    document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("car");
 var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
  }
}
function clearLights() {
    document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
    document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
    document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
}
```

```css
#traffic-light {
    height: 250px;
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin: 30px 0;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;   
    z-index: 1;
}

.bulb {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #111;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 25px auto;
    transition: background 500ms;
}
     html {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
        box-sizing: inherit;
    }
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #09283d, #1b415c, #29516c, #6e8ea5, #7cadd0, #7cadd0, #7cadd0, #7cadd0, #6e8ea5, #3a6583, #1a4461, #09283d);
    background-size: 2400% 2400%;
    animation: dayNight  60s ease infinite;
    }

@keyframes dayNight {
    0%{background-position:25% 0%}
    50%{background-position:76% 100%}
    100%{background-position:25% 0%}
}
    @keyframes driving {
        0% {
            left: -25%;
        }
        10% {
            bottom: 0%;
        }
        20% {
            transform: scale(0.5) rotateZ(-5deg);
            bottom: 5%
        }
        25% {
            transform: scale(0.5) rotateZ(0deg);
        }
        40% {
            transform: scale(0.5) rotateZ(5deg);
        }
        50% {
            transform: scale(0.5) rotateZ(0deg);
        }
        100% {
            left: 110%;
            bottom: 10%;
            transform: scale(0.5) rotateZ(0deg);
        }
    }
    @keyframes road-moving {
        100% {
            transform: translate(-2400px);
        }
    }
    @keyframes wheelsRotation {
        100% {
            transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }
@keyframes moon {
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
   100% {
    transform: translate(80px, -140px);
  }
}
@keyframes sun-moon {
    from { transform:rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
    /*   CAR CONTAINER   */
    
    .car-container {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -10%;
        width: 430px;
        height: 300px;
        animation: driving 5s infinite linear;
        transform: scale(0.5);
    }
    .car-container:after {
        content: "";
        width: 426px;
        height: 1px;
        margin-top: 88px;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: -3%;
        z-index: -1;
        bottom: 0;
        box-shadow: 2px -15px 25px 2px #000000;
    }
    /*   WHEELS   */
    
    .wheel1,
    .wheel2 {
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        background-color: grey;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 20px solid black;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        animation: wheelsRotation 1s infinite linear;
    }
    .wheel1 {
        left: 5%;
    }
    .wheel1-top,
    .wheel2-top {
        bottom: 48px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 106px;
        height: 80px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        z-index: 5;
        box-shadow: 0px 13px 3px 0px rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.53);
        transform: rotateX(180deg);
    }
    .wheel1-top {
        left: 7%;
    }
    .wheel2-top {
        right: 7%;
    }
    .wheel2 {
        right: 5%;
    }
    .wheel-dot1,
    .wheel-dot2 {
        width: 10px;
        height: 25px;
        background-color: black;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .wheel-dot3,
    .wheel-dot4 {
        width: 25px;
        height: 10px;
        background-color: black;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .wheel-dot1 {
        top: 10%;
        left: 45%;
    }
    .wheel-dot2 {
        bottom: 10%;
        left: 45%;
    }
    .wheel-dot3 {
        top: 45%;
        right: 10%;
    }
    .wheel-dot4 {
        top: 45%;
        left: 10%;
    }
    .door {
        width: 110px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 3px solid #B57A84;
        position: absolute;
        left: 36%;
        top: 16px;
        border-radius: 10% 40% 10% 10%;
    }
    .door-knob {
        width: 30px;
        height: 14px;
        background-color: #E8E6E6;
        border-radius: 30%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 20%;
        top: 5%;
        border: 1px solid lightcoral;
    }
    .car-top1 {
        border-radius: 25% 40% 0 0;
        background-color: #6A1621;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 250px;
        height: 130px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 4%;
    }
    .window1,
    .window2 {
        background-color: #E2F0F6;
        border-radius: 5px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 40%;
        height: 60%;
        margin: 17px;
        border: 9px solid #BF6D7B;
    }
    .window1 {
        left: 0;
        border-top-left-radius: 30%;
    }
    .window2 {
        right: 0;
        border-top-right-radius: 50%;
    }
    .car-top2 {
        border-radius: 100px 200px 0 0;
        background-color: #25659C;
        */ border: 10px solid #72252F;
        background-color: #9C2535;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 430px;
        height: 140px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 20%;
    }
    .road {
        width: 250%;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: #585858;
        border-top: 10px solid #756D6D;
        border-bottom: 20px solid #756D6D;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0%;
        margin-left: -10px;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .road::before {
        content: " ";
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 0;
        top: -17px;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        border: 5px solid black;
    }
    .road-top-half {
        height: 15px;
        width: 250%;
        position: absolute;
        left: -10%;
        top: 30px;
        border-top: 40px dashed white;
        margin-top: 25px;
        animation: road-moving 10s infinite linear;
        transition: all 3s linear;
    }
    .skyline {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 205px;
        padding: 0;
        left: 110%;
        animation: road-moving 10s infinite linear;
        transition: all 8s linear;
    }
    .building1 {
        width: 220px;
        height: 450px;
        background-color: #211919;
        position: relative;
    }
    .building1-shadow {
        border-top: 15px solid transparent;
        border-right: 60px solid rgb(44, 37, 37);
        border-bottom: 15px solid #000;
        border-left: 15px solid transparent;
        height: 450px;
        width: 200px;
        position: absolute;
        left: -199px;
    }
    .building-left-half,
    .building-right-half {
        height: 300px;
        width: 50px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        border-left: 16px dashed #A9D2C7;
        border-right: 16px dashed rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.19);
        margin-top: 25px;
    }
    .building-left-half {
        left: 10px;
        padding: 25px;
    }
    .building-right-half {
        right: 10px;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    .moon {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: rgb(207, 207, 212);
        margin: auto;
        box-shadow: 0 0 60px gold, 0 0 100px rgb(185, 160, 24), inset 0 5px 12px 26px #F5F5F5, inset -2px 8px 15px 36px #E6E6DB;
        transition: 1s;
        transition: 1s;
        right:370px;
        top: 30px;
        position: absolute;
        animation: sun-moon 40s  2s linear infinite;
        transform-origin: 50% 500px;
    }

/*Headlights*/
.car-top1:after {
    width: 13px;
    height: 37px;
    background-color: #BACCDA;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -63px;
    right: -168px;
    z-index: 10;
    content: " ";
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-left-style: none;
    transform: rotate(-15deg);
}

    .car-top2:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 7px;
    right: -340px;
    content: " ";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 80px solid transparent;
    border-right: 500px solid rgba(191,188,87,0.7);
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-mask-box-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, black, transparent);
    -webkit-mask-box-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, black, transparent);
    -webkit-mask-box-image: linear-gradient(to right, black, transparent);
    transform: rotate(-9deg);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="traffic-light">
  <div id="stopLight" class="bulb"></div>
  <div id="slowLight" class="bulb"></div>
  <div id="goLight" class="bulb"></div>
</div>
<div class="skyline car">
  <div class="building1-shadow car"></div>
  <div class="building1 car">
    <div class="building-left-half car"></div>
    <div class="building-right-half car"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="road  car">
  <div class="road-top-half  car"></div>
  <div class="road-bottom-half car"></div>
</div>

<div id="car1" class="car-container car">
  <div class="car-top1 car">
    <div class="window1 car"></div>
    <div class="window2 car"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="car-top2 car">
    <div class="door car">
      <div class="door-knob car"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="car-bottom car">
    <div class="wheel1-top car"></div>
    <div class="wheel1 car">
      <div class="wheel-dot1 car"></div>
      <div class="wheel-dot2 car"></div>
      <div class="wheel-dot3 car"></div>
      <div class="wheel-dot4 car"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="wheel2-top car"></div>
    <div class="wheel2 car">
      <div class="wheel-dot1 car"></div>
      <div class="wheel-dot2 car"></div>
      <div class="wheel-dot3 car"></div>
      <div class="wheel-dot4 car"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the while loop blocks execution of the animation, causing the condition it is checking for to never be fulfilled. There are two ways to approach this:

1. check the condition every time the browser renders a frame, using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame);
2. check periodically using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Below, I demonstrate the second approach. When the light goes red, a check is started in an interval that will stop the car when it is close. The interval is [cleared](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) as soon as the car is stopped.

This seems to work well. Note that you would probably want to clear the interval when the light turns yellow or green before the car got to the light. This is *not* in the below demo, for simplicity.

Another note: you are using the `-webkit-` prefix in your code, but you may want to consider using [other prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state#Browser_compatibility) as well. And using the version without any prefix, for when that is implemented.

```js
document.getElementById('stopLight').onclick = illuminateRed;
document.getElementById('slowLight').onclick = illuminateYellow;
document.getElementById('goLight').onclick = illuminateGreen;




function illuminateGreen() {
  clearLights();
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "green";
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("car");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
  }
}

function illuminateRed() {
  clearLights();
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "red";

  var checkAndStopCarInterval = null,
      checkAndStopCar = function() {
        var positionCar = $('#car1').position();
        var percentCarLeft = positionCar.left / $(window).width() * 100;
        var positionPan = $('#traffic-light').position();
        var percentPanLeft = (positionPan.left / $(window).width() * 100) - 10;

        if ((percentCarLeft.toFixed(0) >= percentPanLeft.toFixed(0) - 10) && (percentCarLeft.toFixed(0) <= percentPanLeft.toFixed(0) + 5)) {
          var x = document.getElementsByClassName("car");
          for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "paused";
          }

          clearInterval(checkAndStopCarInterval);
        }
      };
  checkAndStopCarInterval = setInterval(checkAndStopCar, 50);
}

function illuminateYellow() {
  clearLights();
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "orange";
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("car");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
  }
}

function clearLights() {
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
}
```

```css
#traffic-light {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.bulb {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 25px auto;
  transition: background 500ms;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #09283d, #1b415c, #29516c, #6e8ea5, #7cadd0, #7cadd0, #7cadd0, #7cadd0, #6e8ea5, #3a6583, #1a4461, #09283d);
  background-size: 2400% 2400%;
  animation: dayNight 60s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes dayNight {
  0% {
    background-position: 25% 0%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 76% 100%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 25% 0%
  }
}

@keyframes driving {
  0% {
    left: -25%;
  }
  10% {
    bottom: 0%;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.5) rotateZ(-5deg);
    bottom: 5%
  }
  25% {
    transform: scale(0.5) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.5) rotateZ(5deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.5) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    left: 110%;
    bottom: 10%;
    transform: scale(0.5) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes road-moving {
  100% {
    transform: translate(-2400px);
  }
}

@keyframes wheelsRotation {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes moon {
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(80px, -140px);
  }
}

@keyframes sun-moon {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}


/*   CAR CONTAINER   */

.car-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10%;
  width: 430px;
  height: 300px;
  animation: driving 5s infinite linear;
  transform: scale(0.5);
}

.car-container:after {
  content: "";
  width: 426px;
  height: 1px;
  margin-top: 88px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -3%;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 2px -15px 25px 2px #000000;
}


/*   WHEELS   */

.wheel1,
.wheel2 {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: wheelsRotation 1s infinite linear;
}

.wheel1 {
  left: 5%;
}

.wheel1-top,
.wheel2-top {
  bottom: 48px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 106px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 5;
  box-shadow: 0px 13px 3px 0px rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.53);
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.wheel1-top {
  left: 7%;
}

.wheel2-top {
  right: 7%;
}

.wheel2 {
  right: 5%;
}

.wheel-dot1,
.wheel-dot2 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
}

.wheel-dot3,
.wheel-dot4 {
  width: 25px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
}

.wheel-dot1 {
  top: 10%;
  left: 45%;
}

.wheel-dot2 {
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 45%;
}

.wheel-dot3 {
  top: 45%;
  right: 10%;
}

.wheel-dot4 {
  top: 45%;
  left: 10%;
}

.door {
  width: 110px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #B57A84;
  position: absolute;
  left: 36%;
  top: 16px;
  border-radius: 10% 40% 10% 10%;
}

.door-knob {
  width: 30px;
  height: 14px;
  background-color: #E8E6E6;
  border-radius: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 5%;
  border: 1px solid lightcoral;
}

.car-top1 {
  border-radius: 25% 40% 0 0;
  background-color: #6A1621;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  height: 130px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 4%;
}

.window1,
.window2 {
  background-color: #E2F0F6;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: 17px;
  border: 9px solid #BF6D7B;
}

.window1 {
  left: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 30%;
}

.window2 {
  right: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}

.car-top2 {
  border-radius: 100px 200px 0 0;
  background-color: #25659C;
  */ border: 10px solid #72252F;
  background-color: #9C2535;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 430px;
  height: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20%;
}

.road {
  width: 250%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #585858;
  border-top: 10px solid #756D6D;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #756D6D;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  padding: 0;
}

.road::before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: -17px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.road-top-half {
  height: 15px;
  width: 250%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -10%;
  top: 30px;
  border-top: 40px dashed white;
  margin-top: 25px;
  animation: road-moving 10s infinite linear;
  transition: all 3s linear;
}

.skyline {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 205px;
  padding: 0;
  left: 110%;
  animation: road-moving 10s infinite linear;
  transition: all 8s linear;
}

.building1 {
  width: 220px;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: #211919;
  position: relative;
}

.building1-shadow {
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 60px solid rgb(44, 37, 37);
  border-bottom: 15px solid #000;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  height: 450px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -199px;
}

.building-left-half,
.building-right-half {
  height: 300px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  border-left: 16px dashed #A9D2C7;
  border-right: 16px dashed rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.19);
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.building-left-half {
  left: 10px;
  padding: 25px;
}

.building-right-half {
  right: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.moon {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgb(207, 207, 212);
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 60px gold, 0 0 100px rgb(185, 160, 24), inset 0 5px 12px 26px #F5F5F5, inset -2px 8px 15px 36px #E6E6DB;
  transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
  right: 370px;
  top: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  animation: sun-moon 40s 2s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: 50% 500px;
}


/*Headlights*/

.car-top1:after {
  width: 13px;
  height: 37px;
  background-color: #BACCDA;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -63px;
  right: -168px;
  z-index: 10;
  content: " ";
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-left-style: none;
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
}

.car-top2:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 7px;
  right: -340px;
  content: " ";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 80px solid transparent;
  border-right: 500px solid rgba(191, 188, 87, 0.7);
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-mask-box-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, black, transparent);
  -webkit-mask-box-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, black, transparent);
  -webkit-mask-box-image: linear-gradient(to right, black, transparent);
  transform: rotate(-9deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="traffic-light">
  <div id="stopLight" class="bulb"></div>
  <div id="slowLight" class="bulb"></div>
  <div id="goLight" class="bulb"></div>
</div>
<div class="skyline car">
  <div class="building1-shadow car"></div>
  <div class="building1 car">
    <div class="building-left-half car"></div>
    <div class="building-right-half car"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="road  car">
  <div class="road-top-half  car"></div>
  <div class="road-bottom-half car"></div>
</div>

<div id="car1" class="car-container car">
  <div class="car-top1 car">
    <div class="window1 car"></div>
    <div class="window2 car"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="car-top2 car">
    <div class="door car">
      <div class="door-knob car"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="car-bottom car">
    <div class="wheel1-top car"></div>
    <div class="wheel1 car">
      <div class="wheel-dot1 car"></div>
      <div class="wheel-dot2 car"></div>
      <div class="wheel-dot3 car"></div>
      <div class="wheel-dot4 car"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="wheel2-top car"></div>
    <div class="wheel2 car">
      <div class="wheel-dot1 car"></div>
      <div class="wheel-dot2 car"></div>
      <div class="wheel-dot3 car"></div>
      <div class="wheel-dot4 car"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```